# Orbit of rank-one projection under compact group action

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group and let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space with a Hermitian inner product.
Let
$$\alpha : G \to U(V)$$
be an irreducible unitary representation.  Then this gives rise to an action $\beta$ of $G$ on $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ given by
$$ \beta_x(T) = \alpha_x T \alpha_x^*.  $$

If $P = P^* = P^2$ is a rank-one projection in $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}$, then so is $\beta_x(P)$ for each $x \in G$, i.e. the whole orbit consists of projections.  I would like to find conditions which guarantee that these projections span the entire algebra of endomorphisms of $V$.

#### Question:

Is it known when

$$ \mathrm{span} \{ \beta_x (P) \mid x \in G \} = \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)?  $$

Some partial data:

1. If $G$ is a compact Lie group and $P$ is the projection onto the span of the highest (or lowest) weight vector, then the condition holds.
2. If $G = SU(2)$ and $V$ is the three-dimensional irreducible representation, this can fail for some $P$.  For instance, take $P$ to be the projection onto the (one-dimensional) space of vectors of weight $0$.

I am mainly interested in the situation for finite groups and for compact Lie groups, but if there is anything more general out there I would of course be interested in that as well.

Comment: If I understand your question, it's as to when $T$ is a "cyclic vector" for $End(V) = V^\ast \otimes V$, not that that helps me so much.

Comment: @Allen, yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: There is something I don't understand in your question. The projections always lie in the proper subspace of Hermitian endomorphisms ($P^*=P$), so they can never span $End(V)$.  

Comment: @Claudio, that is not true.  For instance if $P$ is Hermitian, $iP$ is anti-Hermitian.  Any operator can be decomposed into a linear combination of Hermitian operators: $T = \frac{1}{2}(T + T^*) + i \frac{1}{2i}(T-T^*)$.

Comment: i.e. the Hermitian endomorphisms do not form a subspace.

Comment: Examples are the solutions of the Zauner problem, where P is the projection onto the span of a fiducal vector and G the Heisenberg group whose orbit consists of the projections onto the equiangular lines.